# Android-SQLiteConstraintException error code 19: constraint failed

Tags: android, sqlite, error-code

I know you have many questions on here about this error, but I cannot understand why all the fields appears to be filled correctly on Logcat, but even so the failure occurs.

Here is the creation of the table:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String ddl = "CREATE TABLE Politician (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE , idpolitician INTEGER NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL, picture TEXT , position TEXT NOT NULL, country TEXT NOT NULL, state TEXT NOT NULL, city TEXT NOT NULL);";

        db.execSQL(ddl);

    }
```

Here is where I tried to save.

```
public void savePolitician(Politician politician) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("idpolitician", politician.getId());
        values.put("name", politician.getName());
        values.put("picture", politician.getPictureFilename());
        values.put("position", politician.getPosition());
        values.put("country", politician.getCountry());
        values.put("state", politician.getState());
        values.put("city", politician.getCity());

        mDatabase.insert("Politician", null, values);

    }
```

And here is the LogCat:

```
01-08 04:03:31.149  32633-32633/? E/Database﹕ [SQLiteDatabase.java:1428:insert()] Error inserting 

state=SP position=governador picture=example idpolitician=1 city=Sao Paulo country=Brasil name=Alckmin

    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1582)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1426)
            at com.politify.dao.DbManegament.savePolitician(DbManegament.java:44)
```

As you can see all the fields are filled. Anyone can help and tell what i`m doing wrong

Comment: Are you entering any duplicate values?

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall so any possible old database gets deleted and your `onCreate()` is called again. Thinking that there's a database file with older version of the schema with different constraints.

Comment: Yes, I tried to add 3 diferent items. They have the same state and country, but diferent values for idpolitician, name and picture.
But this error I got from the first item. There is no politician in the table yet.

Comment: @MárcioPaiva looks like your primary key already exists. Delete the old db and have a new one.

Comment: I am a begginer so sorry if it seems stupid.
When I run it into a smartphone it automatically delete the old version and create a new one or not?

Comment: @MárcioPaiva No, `onCreate()` is only called if the database file doesn't exist. If it already exists and the stored database version matches your code, you don't get any callback, the file is opened as is.

Answer (score 0):

try remove `AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE` inyour create table script

Answer (score 0):

This is your mistake `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE`

When you are defining any column as Primary Key then you do not need to specify it as UNIQUE. Primary Key is by default UNIQUE.

Comment: I already try 
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT and id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. None of this work. I still get the same error.
I get this definition from a tutorial code and it work in ADT, but not in Android Studio

Comment: can you provide that tutorial's link to us ?

Comment: It is from a private course. In fact they said to put just id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, but when I did this I got a error from duplicates ids. So I put AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE and work it. But I tried what you said and I still got the same error.

Comment: Ok no problem. I double check your query, it is find, I think one or more field's value is blank while inserting the record.

Comment: @MárcioPaiva uninstall and reisntall app. The problem may be that you primary key already exists and hence the exception

Comment: @MárcioPaiva, You are correct, My mistake. Let me check again.

Comment: I uninstall and reisntall and work it.
I think that every time you run the code it automatically delete the old version and replace for a new one.

Comment: @MárcioPaiva, I used your code and create a new sample application and it is working fine with no error at all.